# how can i create better sequences for a word prediction model

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, tensorflow, machine-learning-model

Sorry for the length of the question

```
def create_ds(data, max_len):
    seq = []
    end = 2
    data = data.split(" ")
    for i in range(len(data)):
        try:
            if(end <= max_len):
                x = data[i:i + end]
                end += 1
            else:
                end = 2
                x = data[i:i + end]
                end += 1
            
        except Exception as e :
            print(e)
        
        if(x != ''):
            xs = " ".join([i for i in x if i != ''])
            if(len(xs.split(" ")) >= 2):
                seq.append([xs])
   shuffle(seq)
        
   return seq
```

this i my code for creating sequences
after the sequences have been created i vectorize them using keras TextVectorization layer
the output looks like this

```
      array([  24,    7,  122,   14,   28, 8005,   44, 1031,   48,   13, 2299,
              8,  323,    2,  118,   28, 1391,   50,   11, 9784,  235,   50,
              9,   63,    2,  482, 1052,   31, 1972,    4,    3,  439,    6,
              592,  482,  132,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
              0])
```

and i use the following code to remove the last number is this vectorized sequence to make it the target

#this code will take the vectorized sequences and make targets from those.It takes the vectorized sequences and the size of each sequence and remove the last item in that sequence and make it a target and then replace that by a zero

```
 def extract(ds):
    labels = []
    for i in range(ds.shape[0]):
        labels.append(ds[i][list(ds[i]).index(0)-1])
        ds[i][list(ds[i]).index(0)-1] = 0
    
    return tf.convert_to_tensor(ds), np.array(labels)
  
 features, labels = extract(train_ds.numpy())
```

if you pass this into the the above function

```
     array([  24,    7,  122,   14,   28, 8005,   44, 1031,   48,   13, 2299,
              8,  323,    2,  118,   28, 1391,   50,   11, 9784,  235,   50,
              9,   63,    2,  482, 1052,   31, 1972,    4,    3,  439,    6,
              592,  482,  132,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
              0])
```

it will take the  last 132 and make it into a target and replace its position with a zero

what i want to know is what am i doing wrong here and is there a better way of doing this which is efficient. Sorry for the length of the question

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are padding sequences to be the same length. Another option could be using TensorFlow / Kera's established function -
[tf.keras.utils.pad_sequences](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/pad_sequences)